# Creating a highscore screen with persistent data in BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, java-me, persistent-storage

I'm trying to create a highscore screen with 5 strings. I only want to update the screen 1 string at a time, as I create a new high score. If there is no new or old high score I just use the initialized default of 10.

I have been able to use the BlackBerry api and figure out how to create 1 highscore that works completely. However, I'm absolutely stuck on how to create all 5 and sort them within the persistent mechanics. I don't want to post my code because at this point it is such a mess it would be useless.

For reference I am trying to use a string[] and not a vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this example: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/rim/attachments/rim/java_dev@tkb/14/1/Storing_Persistent_Data_V2.pdf

It demonstrates how you can store different strings in Vector with reference.

Comment: As I mentioned I have already used that information...Anyway my problem is that I don't know how to store one variable at a time...all of the examples store and retrieve things all at once. I would want to store at most 1 item per game, but be able to retrieve 1,2,3 or 4 items all at once depending on the situation.